# The pros and cons of PHP's function checkdnsrr()

Tags: php

I'm currently reading HEAD FIRST PHP and MySQL. I'm at the chapter teaching how to validate email. This book teaches using regular expression to check the localname part of an email, and PHP's built-in function checkdnsrr to check the domain part. 
If the domain is valid, then the email will be valid, and vice versa.

I just tried Apple, and GitHub registration validation, and found that they didn't validate the email field with this way. 
I'm wondering if it's a practical way or not?
I personally reckon that it it a good way, however, if so, why such giant companies like Apple don't use that?

I will be appreciate to hear different perspectives from you.

Comment: You found that Apple, Github didn't do *what* exactly…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with validating email addresses:

- The RFCs specifying what constitutes a valid address are hyper complex and partially contradictory and superseding one another, so actually writing code which neither over validates nor under validates is somewhere between a giant pain in the neck and infeasible.
- Even if you validate the address perfectly according to the spec, and you check that the domain exists, you still have no idea whether the address actually exists or is in use. The only way to know that is to try to send an email to it and see if it bounces. So, why go through all the other trouble first except for some very coarse first filtering?
- It’s more work to implement overly exact validation.
- Trying to validate a domain or an actual address by initiating a network connection to that DNS or SMTP server can be used as a DDoS attack vector. At the scale of Apple, who certainly have the server resources, an attacker could make Apple essentially DDoS smaller domains with lots of spurious email validation requests.

Given all the above, a very simple check like `.+@.+\..+` to weed out obviously lacking input plus actually trying to send the email is typically good enough in practice, and avoids false negatives, complex implementations and too much network traffic.